# Groupby and sum rows to aggregate multiple values of PRODUCT column

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I have a table like this in pandas

```
PERIOD  REGION2 REGION  PRODUCT Production  NSLOG   CHIPS   SSAW
2010    FRANC   cw_eu   PLYC           100     10       5   
2010    FRANC   cw_eu   PLYN           230             30   
2011    FINLA   n_eu    PLYC           800      1       
2011    FINLA   n_eu    PLYN           200              4   
2011    FRANC   cw_eu   PLYC           100      3       
2011    FRANC   cw_eu   PLYN           200      7       2   
2010    AUSTR   cw_eu   CWC            248  57.04   78.78   
2010    AUSTR   cw_eu   CWF            1017                 58.11
2010    AUSTR   cw_eu   DissP          282     93.6          1056
```

and I would like to achieve something like this:

```
PERIOD  REGION2 REGION  PRODUCT Production  NSLOG   CHIPS   SSAW
2010    FRANC   cw_eu   PLY            330     10      35   
2011    FINLA   n_eu    PLY           1000      1       4   
2011    FRANC   cw_eu   PLY            300     10       2   
2010    AUSTR   cw_eu   CWC            248  57.04   78.78   
2010    AUSTR   cw_eu   CWF            1017                 58.11
2010    AUSTR   cw_eu   DissP          282           93.6    1056
```

i.e my goal is to groupby and sum the rows by, PERIOD, REGION2, REGION,PRODUCT but ONLY for those rows where PRODUCT equal PLYC or PLYN leaving all the other rows untouched and return the summed rows with the new name PLY
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first want to group all of your `PLYC` and `PLYN` products and reset the index. You then create the `PRODUCT` column with the new value of `PLY`.

Now, concatenate these grouped results to the data from the original dataframe (but excluding the `PLYC` and `PLYN` products). Then set your index on your desired fields and you're good to go.

```
grouped_products = ['PLYC', 'PLYN']
gb = (df[df.PRODUCT.isin(grouped_products)]
      .groupby(['PERIOD', 'REGION2', 'REGION'])
      .sum()
      .reset_index())
gb['PRODUCT'] = 'PLY'

result = pd.concat([gb, df.loc[~df.PRODUCT.isin(grouped_products), :]], ignore_index=True)
result.set_index(['PERIOD', 'REGION2', 'REGION', 'PRODUCT'], inplace=True)
>>> result.loc[:, ['Production', 'NSLOG', 'CHIPS', 'SSAW']]
                               Production  NSLOG  CHIPS     SSAW
PERIOD REGION2 REGION PRODUCT                                   
2010   FRANC   cw_eu  NaN             330  10.00  35.00      NaN
2011   FINLA   n_eu   NaN            1000   1.00   4.00      NaN
       FRANC   cw_eu  NaN             300  10.00   2.00      NaN
2010   AUSTR   cw_eu  CWC             248  57.04  78.78      NaN
                      CWF            1017    NaN    NaN    58.11
                      DissP           282  93.60    NaN  1056.00
```

Note that any difference in results should only be due to incorrect column alignment when importing your dataset above.